# Why does this Regular Expression not return the correct match?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to return part of a string, I want to return everything before the fist slash:

```
EC22941C/02/ORI
```

Should give me: EC22941C

I have used http://www.regexr.com/ to build up my expression:

```
(EC.+?)\/.+
```

When tested against my text:

```
EC22941C/02/ORI
```

It correctly tells me that the first group is

```
EC22941C
```

When I put it into C#:

```
 public static string GetInstructionRef(string supplierReferenceId)
    {
        // The instruciton ref is the bit before the slash            
        var match = Regex.Match(supplierReferenceId, @"(EC.+?)\/.+");

        if (match == null || match.Groups.Count == 0)
            return "";

        // Return the first group which is the instruction ref
        return match.Groups[0].Value;
    }
```

The result I get back is:

```
EC22941C/02/ORI
```

I have tried a number of different patterns and they all seem to do the same thing.

Does anyone have any idea what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're returning the wrong group index, `0` will return the entire match while `1` returns the matched context of the capturing parentheses — numbered from left to right.

```
return match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Oh man I feel so silly! It was staring me in the face, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
^EC[^\/]+
```

You can simply use this and avoid using groups.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/6

```
string strRegex = @"^EC[^\/]+";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"EC22941C/02/ORI";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `match.Groups[1].Value`.

`match.Groups[0].Value` returns the whole string (if it matches the pattern).

Also, you'd want to change your if condition as well. :)